# Metal Oxide Varistor Identification / Replacement? Component marking IOE241 99P

Tags: identification, mov

[image: Photo of PCB and component]

Could anyone identify the component shown in the image? It is marked 'IOE241 99P'. It is ~12mm in diameter. I believe it is an MOV. The image shows the location on the Power PCB it was removed from. The power board is from a Brother Sewing Machine CS6000i (this machine draws 0.65A at 120V)

This component was destroyed when the board was connected to a 240V / 50Hz AC supply in error. The board expects 120V / 60Hz AC input. I have spent many hours searching for 'IOE241 99P' (and sub-strings of the text) for found nothing. If I cannot identify this component, is there some reasonable substitute component that would work in its place?

I am working my way through the board testing/replacing components as needed. There are no replacement boards available. (The component marked C101 in the image will be replaced too - it is a polypropylene capacitor Class X2 0.1uF - Okaya LE104. The component marked F101 is a fuse - this has already been replaced). Thanks!

Comment: The PCB symbol is a diac.

Comment: Hi serpentinite, The 10E241, a 240V MOV, has been damaged in carrying out it's protective task of blowing the fuse.  In normal circumstances it would have only quenched voltage spikes and lasted longer. Do hope there are no bigger damages.

Comment: Nowadays that symbol is used for DIACs, but it was the original MOV symbol I'm told. Not sure when it switched or how much overlap there was between the two. There are actually similarities between the two, in that at a certain voltage their resistance drops significantly, in both polarities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a paper on choosing a varistor - [https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/varistors/littelfuse_selecting_a_littelfuse_varistor_application_note.pdf][1]

Littelfuse has a ton of staff that will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Just pick one the same diameter in mm and rated for your proper 120VAC mains voltage. It will have roughly the same ability to absorb a transient (joules).

I would not be surprised at all if other things have been killed by the 240VAC though. Particularly, semiconductors such as high-voltage transistors or MOSFETs.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all for the timely advice. It helped me to determine the following:

The MOV '10E241' is a 10mm diameter,240V, high 'E'nergy component. I found two datasheets for such a component:

https://cms.nacsemi.com/content/AuthDatasheets/WPRDD00172-76.pdf
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/ERZ-E10%20Datasheet-1196708.pdf

I also found it available to buy at multiple sites, e.g.
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/ERZ-E10E241?qs=%252B9%2Fcbd0IE0TBcvddNuha9A==

If I am in error, please comment, otherwise - thanks!!

Comment: Anytime, serpentinite!